# FeCl3 to [FeCl4]-

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

A 0.1 M solution of iron(III) chloride in $\ce{POCl3}$ is red and turns yellow on dilution. Titration of red $\ce{FeCl3/POCl3}$ solution with colourless $\ce{[Et4N]+Cl^{-}/POCl3}$ solution causes the colour to change from red to yellow with a sharp end-point at a 1:1 molecular ratio of $\ce{FeCl3:[Et4N]+Cl^{-}}$

Determine the equilibria.

From the molar equivalences it seems straightforward viz:

$$\ce{Fe2Cl6 + 2POCl3 -> 2[FeCl4]- + 2[POCl2]+
}$$

This equilibrium shifting to the right on dilution, giving the yellow $\ce{FeCl4-}$,
followed by:-

$$\ce{[FeCl4]- + [POCl2]+ + [Et4N]+Cl- -> [Et4N]+ + [FeCl4]- + POCl3}$$

but there could be another option:

$$\ce{Fe2Cl6 + 4POCl3 -> [FeCl2(POCl3)4]+ + [FeCl4]-}$$

again, shifting to the right on dilution, followed by:-

$$\ce{[FeCl2(POCl3)4]+ + 2[Et4N]+Cl- \rightleftharpoons 2[Et4N]+ + [FeCl4]- + 4POCl3}$$

any thoughts, anybody?

Comment: Does $\ce{Fe2Cl6}$ exist?!?

Comment: @MaxW ferric chloride dimerises in vapor phase-Wikipedia